# Почему не работает метод inRandomOrder()?

Tags: laravel

Вот мой код:

```
$quiz = Quiz::join('answers as ans','ans.id_ques','=','quizzes.id')
            ->inRandomOrder(1)
            ->get();
        $result = ['quizs' => $quiz];
        dd($quiz);
```

Он выводит все записи, где поля ans.id_ques == quizzes.id, а должен из всех записей 1 рандомную, почему этого не происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в `inRandomOrder` не задается лимит.

Или используйте `limit`:

```
$quiz = Quiz::join('answers as ans','ans.id_ques','=','quizzes.id')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();
```

Или, лучше, если нужна только одна запись, просто через `first`:

```
$quiz = Quiz::join('answers as ans','ans.id_ques','=','quizzes.id')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();
```